# Linux - Directory Check

Tags: linux, bash, directory, rhel

I am trying to write a script to check whether a directory exists and it has the adequate file size. So far I've managed to get a directory check but I've not had much luck checking for the size as well.

BASEDIR needs to be 8GB and WORKDIR 4GB

```
#!/bin/sh
BASEDIR=/opt/app
WORKDIR=$BASEDIR/program/work

if [[ -d "${BASEDIR}" && ! -L "${BASEDIR}" ]] ; then
    echo "Confirmed ${BASEDIR}"
fi

if [[ -d "${WORKDIR}" && ! -L "${WORKDIR}" ]] ; then
    echo "Confirmed ${WORKDIR}"
fi
```

R,

Comment: Check the man page for `du`.

Comment: Better wording would be "available space" instead of "file size", if you do a `ls -l $WORKDIR` it will show you a size and that may be large if there are/were many files in there

Comment: @Ricardo A: You need to let people know if the provided solutions work or not to help you and subsequently close the topic

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to ensure 8G (4G) of free space is available in the chosen directory, not that it is already populated with 8G (4G) worth of files.  (See Inian's answer for the latter case).

You can use **df** to return the available space for a given folder.

```
avail = `df "$BASEDIR" -k --output=avail | tail -1`
if (($avail >= 8*1024*1024)); then echo "Good"; else echo "Not Good"; fi
```